# How to pass etcd credentials to kubernetes api-server?

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, basic-authentication, credentials, etcd

I'm facing this issue since some days ago, and is the following:

I'm trying to start my kubernetes master using hypercube,
but the documentation is missing how to pass the etcd credentials to kubernetes in order to use a given user.

In the api-server configuration I have something like this:

```
- --etcd-servers=http://root:toor@etcd2-0.server:2379,http://root:toor@etcd2-1.server:2379,http://root:toor@etcd2-2.server:
```

Which is the only possible way to set the basic auth parameters of etcd.
(This works great for both etcdctl and etcd REST API.)

But I'm getting the following error:

- F0915 17:25:35.579278       1 controller.go:86] Unable to perform initial IP allocation check: unable to persist the updated service IP allocations: 110: The request requires user authentication (Insufficient credentials) [0]

My etcd is refusing to write into /registry (which is the default folder), but root:toor are the right credentials.

I couldn't find any other configuration parameters for this, and I REALLY, REALLY need to secure my etcd with roles/users.

Please, I need some ideas / solutions if possible.

Comment: Shot in the dark: https://github.com/coreos/etcd/issues/6075 could be related. Or you can try passing the etcd-{ca,cert,key}file flags. More details on the flags: http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-apiserver/

Comment: Nope :(  

My kubernetes is not using the guest role, it needs to use my root one instead.

And regarding the tls flags: Neither :(   I am not using tls between etcd and kubernetes.

Thanks for your time anyways!

Comment: I am stuck with the same issue. Flannel allows "-etcd-username=kubernetes -etcd-password=xx" but the kubernetes api-server does not have such authentication options. :-(